# Bi-directional paging between views arranged in a table

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

I have views arranged in a table. One column of this table represents one Journal article; each row in this column represents one page of this article. Now I have to be able to swipe between articles and between pages as well.

I know how to work with ViewPager and Fragments, I also know about the library: 
https://github.com/JakeWharton/Android-DirectionalViewPager, but this allows paging only in one direction at the same time. Moreover, I actually do not want to page in both directions at the same time, but once I start to move right, the next article must appear, similarly once I move down; the following page of the article must appear...

I can’t use vertical scrolling instead of paging, it is a customer requirement.

I think about the proper approach more than two days, but still can’t figure out how to do that. I think the simplest way is to rewrite DirectionalViewPager by JakeWharton, it seems to be a solid base.

Before I start to do that, I would like to ask Android gurus here on SO: is there some better approach or library to do that?